# cannot boot after shrinking volume

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, disk-management

I have one 1TB HDD on my desktop. It has 3 primary partitions:

1. C: (Boot, Contains Windows)
2. D: (Backup Disk)
3. E: (Another Backup Disk)

Now, I wanted to have another partition for my Linux, so I decided to shrink the volume `D:`. Using Windows Disk Management, I successfully shrink the volume and have a newly RAW partition which is drive `H:`.

My problem starts when I did a reboot. The Windows will not start anymore, a blinking insert cursor appears. No error or any notice at all. I remember I confirm "Yes" to this warning:

[image]

Is there anything that I can do to have my Windows back?

Comment: That.. is strange. You should still be able to boot from the Dynamic Disk. It may prevent you from starting other OS from other partition of the disk, but it should not prevent you from starting the current one. If you still have the original Windows CD, boot from there, and there should be an option to Repair Boot Partition on the CD. I can't remember exactly how / where tho... (maybe google can help)

Comment: The problem is I don't have CDROM here in my desktop.

Comment: Do you have other computer you can use to burn the Windows image into a USB and boot from USB?

Comment: Sadly none, the USB I have is what I use now to run Live Session of Crunchbang so I can browse the Internet for use. 3am here so I'm out of resources. :(

Comment: 3AM.. 6AM here.. but ok.. since you at least have a Linux Live USB working.. can you get yourself a Windows ISO from somewhere, and "burn" that ISO from Crunchbang into another USB? (assuming of course you have a 2nd USB)